# How to discern touch events on stacked HTML elements in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, onclick

Let's suppose I have a div containing a span element, both with an onclick function.
When I click on the div it calls its function, but when I click on the span it calls the span's function first, and then the div's function.
What can I do to call only the span's function and ignore the div's one? 
(in other words, call the function of the bottom element in HTML hierarchy ignoring the rest)

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack would be to set a "shouldIgnoreNext" bool, and ignore the next div-originating call when you receive a span call.

Comment: Thanks but I don't fully understand you, how would you do it?
(Both elements will call the same function, and I need that both could call it individually)

Comment: Pass the element as a parameter of the function.